# Add autoplay to embeded video

Tags: javascript, video, swfobject

I am embedding a video on my webpage using SWFObject in my Javascript. I would like the video to play automatically on page load. I know that for many video sites they have codes like adding '&autoplay=true' to the embed link. However, the provider of my video does not allow autoplay in that manner (verified this by emailing them directly).

My question is, is there any way to get it to autoplay through Javascript? I've tried adding flashvars to the SWFObject, trying to simulate a mouse click on the object through .click() but none of it seems to be working. My project will be significantly harmed if I can't jimmy a way to make videos play on page load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a FLV file or a SWF?  Easiest would be to ask the provider how to auto play.

You can try using SWFObject's callback:
https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api

... and then trying to get it to play();

Comment: It's a linked video, so I'm not entirely sure if it's SWF or FLV. Customer support from the video provider told me autoplay is not possible in that manner. I've tried SWFObject.Play(); and while it doesn't return any errors it also doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is the filetype of the included file? You may be out of luck unless there's some interface provided (the callback doesn't provide a SWF reference, as I thought).